# Actionscript - Event That Notifies When Image Source Has Changed AND is Done Loading

Tags: actionscript-3, events, flex4

I am looking for an event that fires after an image's source property has been changed, and the image display object has loaded the new data.  I thought the 'complete' event was the way to go, but it seems to fires as soon as the source has changed, BUT before the image is done loading.  In the snippet below, I am trying to get the imgMap_completeHandler to fire once imgMap has been updated with the bytes from doExport().

```
public function doExport(bytes:ByteArray):void
{
    FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addElement(this);
    imgMap.source = bytes;
}

protected function imgMap_completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var pngEncoder:PNGEncoder = new PNGEncoder();
    var snapShot:ImageSnapshot = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(this,0,pngEncoder);
    export = snapShot.data;
    dispatchEvent(new Event("exportComplete"));
}

<s:Image id="imgMap" complete="imgMap_completeHandler(event)"  width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

Comment: do you have event/function called exportComplete

Comment: Perhaps INIT will work. I'm not familiar with the Image component, but in many other Flash components, INIT is the event that fires after the data changes and is available.

Comment: Puzzling.  From the docs, it definitely sounds like this should work. Another one to try is the `ready` event, but from looking at the *BitmapImage.as* (a lot of *Image.as* is just a wrapper of this), it seems like the `ready` gets fired before the `complete`.

Comment: Have you tried the event handler for updateComplete?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to extend Image class and source method to do that?

You may only have to create a standard event just after the

```
public function source(....)
{
    [super source...]
    dispatchEvent(new Event('Loaded'));
}
```

Hope it helps!